# MPMediaPickerController missing search functionality on the iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, search, mpmediapickercontroller

When setting up an `MPMediaPickerController` with the same code the search functionality works on the iPhone but not on the iPad. There's a search box in the picker on iPhone, but not on iPad.

Is there a way to enable this functionality on the iPad?

Comment: @0x7fffffff you should write this comment as an answer

Comment: @AranMulholland A couple months late! :p

Answer (score 1):

I filed a bug report about this (ID: 12157125) back in August nothing has come from it yet, so no there is no way to enable this functionality. However, you could remake the picker from the ground up using a combination of a [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and some [MPMediaQueries](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaQuery_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html), leaving you free to add your own search functionality.